# Cordova Hybrid App Design - Controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to develop an Application using Cordova framework. My application needs to have many controllers to work. So keeping all the Controllers in the same file will be Bulky as the Code size will increase. So maintainability of the code will be lost.

So for each Controller which Programming Design approach is suggested:

## 1. Having one main `App.js` file and writing all the Controllers inside it. And finally importing only `App.js` file in `index.html` file.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('ControllerA', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

myApp.controller('ControllerB', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);

myApp.controller('ControllerC', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

## 2. Having multiple js files for each controller and importing all in the main `index.html` file:

Main App.js file:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

ControllerA.js file:

```
myApp.controller('ControllerA', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

ControllerB.js file:

```
myApp.controller('ControllerB', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

ControllerC.js file:

```
myApp.controller('ControllerC', ['$scope', function($scope) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Certainly for version control purposes it's ideal to separate out those controller into their own files. I think your project could benefit from a task runner such as [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or [GulpJS](http://gulpjs.com/).

If you go with GulpJS you could setup your gulpfile like so:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

var concat  = require('gulp-concat');
var ug      = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename  = require('gulp-rename');

// Minfy all assets into a single file.
gulp.task('default', function() {
    var files = [
        '/js/controller/*.js'
    ];

    return gulp.src(files)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(ug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../js'));
});
```

And then run `gulp` from the command line. On your page you'd load the whole bundle.js which would include your app and any number of controllers, services, and directives.

Comment: What does gup do? Minify scripts into one that you can import in index.html main page.

Comment: Correct, it's a javascript task runner which helps you do things like concatenate and minify javascript files to be imported with a single request.